# Display data in sorting order based on arrived time with current date using LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

```
public ViewResult Index1(DateTime? Startdate)
{
    Startdate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    DateTime Enddate = DateTime.Now;
    string AM = "AM";
    var value10 = from res in db.BookingArriveds where (res.BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime >= Startdate && res.BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime <= Enddate) orderby res.BookingArrivedEnquiredTime.Contains(AM) descending orderby res.BookingArrivedEnquiredTime descending select res;   

    return View(value10);
}
```

I have a one table. Table having a `arrivedtime` column with datatype is `varchar` and another column `arriveddate`. Now I want to sort `arrivedtime` with current date.

Data like this

```
    (03:30 PM,10:30 AM, 04:05 PM, 11:08 AM, 08:30 PM, 05:20 AM,12:08 AM ) 
with current date(18-03-2015).
```

Now I would like to sort the `arrivedtime` like

```
08:30 PM, 04:05 PM,03:30 PM,05:20 AM,10:30 AM, 12:08 AM.
```

I want display data in sorting the `arrivedtime` using linq query based on current date. How to write `linq` query for sorting time?

Comment: how sort the time based on time including am and pm

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your object, but I guess a simple `.OrderByDescending(x=>x.arrivedTime)` appended to your linq statement should do the job.

Comment: var value10 = from bar in db.BookingArriveds
                         where (bar.BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime == searchString)
                         orderby bar.arrivedTimedescending 
                         select bar;

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments to the **Rober's** answer, you are looking to order records based on timestamp for a given date.

```
 BookingArriveds.Where(c=>DateTime.ParseExact(c.ArrivedDate,"yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == searchDate)
                .OrderBy(c=>c.ArrivedTime);
```

You mary refer some [Working Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OrQfaj) here.

Comment: it will work on only static data not working on dynamic data means i am retrieving data from database

Comment: I am trying like this    ---------------------------->                                                                    var value10 = from res in db.BookingArriveds where (res.BookingArrivedEnquiredDateTime == Startdate) orderby res.BookingArrivedEnquiredTime.Contains(AM) descending orderby res.BookingArrivedEnquiredTime descending select res;